# Text distortion in primefaces chart

Tags: google-chrome, jsf, primefaces, webkit

I am using a primefaces barchat. which has an text distortion issue in chrome browser. when i checked the official demo page, same issue is there too (https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/bar.xhtml?jfwid=5bfdc). Problem exists in webkit browsers only. Is there any workaround for it. thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue on primefaces 12.0.0. I just found out that if I disable Accelerated 2D canvas in about:flags in Chrome the issue goes away. Hopefully a workarround will be found without the requirement of changing such a setting client-side.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned on the PF ticket I doubt you will get much help as those old jQuery Charts are dead and have not received many updates.

Also PrimeFaces has deprecated jQuery Charts in 10.0.0 with removal in 13.0.0.

See: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/8773

I recommend moving to the ChartsJS version of the charts which are supported and work on all modern browsers.

Comment: Awesome! Could you please point out how to manually switch to ChartJS?

Comment: Okay I think my starting point is to move from
import org.primefaces.model.chart.LineChartModel;
to
import org.primefaces.model.charts.line.LineChartModel;

Again many thanks